# Collecting SMTP server using Mailkit with Mimekit

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

While trying to send an e-mail using MailKit and MimeKit,is there a way to collect the SMTP Output?.

ps: I am trying to migrate my email code from Easymail to Mimekit and Mailkit and I apologize if this is a rather basic query.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's actually a [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog) about this, but for convenience, I'll paste it here:

All of MailKit's client implementations have a constructor that takes a nifty [IProtocolLogger](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_IProtocolLogger.htm) interface for logging client/server communications. Out of the box, you can use the handy [ProtocolLogger](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_ProtocolLogger.htm) class. Here are some examples of how to use it:

```
// log to a file called 'smtp.log'
var client = new SmtpClient (new ProtocolLogger ("smtp.log"));

// log to standard output (i.e. the console)
var client = new SmtpClient (new ProtocolLogger (Console.OpenStandardOutput ()));
```

Comment: Thanks!. I am working on an application that sends mails to 1000 people.I will need to record every send with the result. I just need to know if it was sent or whether it failed with an exception code.
Is there a simple way to just collect the SMTP server response codes synchronously?. I noticed that the method void Data (FormatOptions options, MimeMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ITransferProgress progress) does have
an event being triggered  OnMessageSent (new MessageSentEventArgs (message, response.Response));. Is there a way for me to collect that after each send?.

Comment: Yes. It's emitted after every message is sent.

Comment: @jstedfast using the new ProtocolLogger ("smtp.log") rewrites the LOG file everytime I run the program, how can I append the file ? so that the previous data is not deleted ?

Comment: You could implement your own IProtocolLogger and use that, but the default ProtocolLogger class does not support that.

Comment: @jstedfast Used this approach to create a quick and dirty [implementation for log4Net](https://gist.github.com/lankymart/8867fb39c43ced877ec23333f339640d).

Comment: Hi @jstedfast, is there a way to convert the log into a string without writing to a file? I tried grabbing the Stream to convert it to a string, but it looks like the Stream needs to open a file (and not be null) otherwise it throws an exception.

`using( var client = new SmtpClient( new MailKit.ProtocolLogger( LogStream ) ) )`

The idea here is to record the log to a database field as a string. Thanks.

Comment: You can use a MemoryStream instead of a filename. I would avoid trying to convert the stream data into a string, though, because the data is not guaranteed to all be the same charset. Just save it to the database as a binary blob.

Comment: @jstedfast When I use  `// log to a file called 'smtp.log'
var client = new SmtpClient (new ProtocolLogger ("smtp.log"));
`. It throws an error on the next iteration saying file in use. Can't check the contents unless I stop the application. How to resolve this?

Comment: @KrishnanVenkiteswaran I am looking for the same solution where you can log all emails sent. Were you able to find it? logger that appends the logs in the same file.

Comment: @Zedverse07 @krishnan-venkiteswaran As of MailKit 3.x, the Send and SendAsync methods return a `string` that contains the SMTP server response to the DATA command. You can "parse" that to find the token you are looking for.